# Is possible to embed some constants in WebSocket class without directly editing WebSocket.m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have in framework in inherited project one class which I use to send data to server and in function call specify key like 
`[[WebSocket instance] key:@"end_session"];`
Is possible to embed some constants in WebSocket class without directly editing WebSocket.m file ?
( I want to avoid if I need to change key string to change on all location and I would rather have constants like END_SESSION = @"end_session" like part of more specified WebSocket class ).
( I can create Constants.h file and put all constants inside and add

`#import "Constants.h"`
 in `*.pch` file but I would more like to have like a part of WebSocket).

Answer (score 0):

Declare constants in WebSocket.m file like this

```
extern NSString * const kSomeConstantString;
extern const NSInteger kSomeConstantInteger;
```

And anywhere else in you project, declare there values like this

```
NSString * const kSomeConstantString = @"SomeString";
const NSInteger kSomeConstantInteger = 15;
```

Note, you can create a Constants.m file, and you don't need to import that anywhere.

Comment: @IOgg3r I am very new to objective c, I thought that I can do this through category without any editing of WebSocket.m file ( I download new version of WebSocket framework than I need again to add those lines to .m file)